# NULL when using fopen with xcode

Tags: ios, fopen

I am trying to initialize a multidimensional array from a file using `C` for a iPhone 4inch app but I can't open up the file using `fopen`.
Whenever I try this I get a `NULL`:

```
FILE  *f;
f=fopen("/level1.rez", "r");

if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    //exit (0);
}
```

I am not sure how to open files using `C`.

I tried this already:

I printed out the current working directory using `getcwd` but all I got was "/" and when I attached that to the file name I still got `NULL`.

I read that if you go to `product > scheme > edit scheme` then options you can change the current working directory but I don't see that option.

Also I read that you can use absolute paths like: `/users/name/desktop/program`
but I am new to iOS development so I don't know if that is a good idea.

So how do I get `fopen` to work?

Comment: Have you tried `level1.rez` as the filename instead? `/` is usually the root directory.

Comment: yah that was my first attempt at getting it to work. And you edited xcode 5 out of the title but I think this might be a xcode 5 specific question since the suggestions other users mentioned did not apply to my project setup.

Comment: It would be better to add the `C` tag then `Xcode`. If you can get the code to work using another IDE, but still not in Xcode, then it would be an Xcode issue. The thing is you mention editing the scheme to change the working directory, but you are running the app on the device. That is sandboxed in its own directory. Have you bundled `level1.rez` as a resource, i.e. added it to the project?

Comment: I think I did. I did not create the file somewhere else but in xcode if that is what you are asking. I went new > file > other > empty and created level1.rez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN specify absolute paths in iOS, but the path in your example is probably used in Mac OS, which is laid out a little differently.  You can specify paths to fopen() as you say, but there is more work to finding out what the first part of that path really is.

The iOS puts all AppStore apps into folders with randomly generated sandbox directory names.  It is basically the the hexadecimal string of a GUID.  So you need to use methods from iOS frameworks to get the first part of the path (or URL) to your file.

If the file is part of the app bundle so it can ship with the app, then you will need to use NSBundle methods to find the path to the file.

If the file is generated or downloaded after the app starts up on the device, then you need to use NSFileManager methods to determine the path to the directory of the file.  (Typically the Documents directory. You can build a directory structure of your choice within the sandbox.)

Comment: So should I abandon opening the file using c and just use objective c? I am not sure what you are saying.

Comment: @rezen__ There's no reason to avoid the C functions like `fopen`. You just need to pass the proper path which you need to obtain using the appropriate Objective-C methods.